CMake - How to make my .exe search for libraries in additional directory
I have this in my main CMakeLists.txt:
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Install CACHE PATH "install here" FORCE)
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Install/bin  CACHE PATH "install here" FORCE)
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Install/bin/lib  CACHE PATH "install here" FORCE)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/lib  CACHE PATH "Set search lib dir." FORCE)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH} "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/lib")
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH} "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/lib")
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/lib  CACHE PATH "Set search lib dir." FORCE)
set_target_properties(
        Common
        AuthServer
        WorldServer
    PROPERTIES
        ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/lib
        LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/lib
        RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin
)

However this does not make my WorldServer.exe to search in the lib folder located exactly next to it. In order to make my WorldServer.exe start I have to copy all of the .dll files from ./lib folder and place them next to it.
Is there a way to make my .exe search in additional folder for the .dll it needs ?

The algorithm for search dlls is described e.g. here. No CMake command or property adds additional directory to search.

BTW, setting RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY property affects on location for both .exe and .dll which are built with CMake. In you case both of them should be created in bin/ subdirectory. I don't know why with such setting you have .dll produced in the lib/ subdirectory.

@Tsyvarev I have added SetDllDirectoryA("lib"); to the lpFileName  but it did not changed. Anything. Any other suggestion ?

"I have added SetDllDirectoryA("lib"); to the lpFileName" - So you CMakeLists.txt is absolutely unrelated to that setting. What about removing that irrelevant CMake code from the question, and add information relevant to your setting? Probably, you have done something in a wrong way, but without additional information it is impossible to say what is exactly wrong.
